# vue : can't navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm new to vue and i have created a dynamic page that gets questions,user name, and categories from API ,every thing is showing fine but my problem is i want to make those dynamic (user name for example) is clickable so when ever i click on it it should take me to user's profile with same name, i have tried to do a clickable div but only the url route changes not the content of the page (it's not taking me to the profile page), also as u see in my code i created a function in methods that saved my clickable user in index and i'm trying to show this user saved in index in my profile page but i didn't figure out how to do it, any help please?

```html
hom.vue

 <p>Asked by:  </p>
  
  <div id="user" v-for="(user, index) in users"
   :key="index"> 
 <div @click="selectedUser(index)">{{ user }}</div>
   
      </div>
      
      export default {
 props: {
  
    question1: Object

  },
     data() {
    return {
     
      selectedIndex: null,
      
    };
  },
  watch: {
    question1: {
   

      handler() {
        this.selectedIndex = null;
       
      },
    },
  },
  computed: {
    users() {
      let users = [this.question1.user];
      return answers;
    },
  
  },
  methods: {//here i saved the user that i clicked on in index in order to show it to the profile page
    selectedUser(index) {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
       this.$router.push('/Profile')


    },
  }
}




profile.vue

<template>

  <div class="container" width=800px>


  <b-row id="asked-info">
  <p>Welcome to the profile of:  </p>
  
  <div id="user" v-for="(user, index) in users"
   :key="index"> 
  
   {{ user }}
      </div>
    
     


  </b-row>
 
  </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
 
  props: {
  
    question1: Object

  },
  
  computed: {
    users() {
      let users = [this.question1.user];
     // here i'm not able to figure out how will the user i saved in index (the user i clicked on) will show here
      return users;
    },
  
  },
}
</script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the index via props to route components.

Your `selectedUser` function would be like:

```
selectedUser(index) {
   this.$router.push({ path: `/Profile/${index}` })
},
```

In your Router instance:

```
routes: [
    { 
        path: '/profile/:index', 
        component: Profile, 
        props: true //to specify that you are using props
    },
    //your other routes
]
```

Then in the `profile.vue`, you can access the index by this syntax: `this.$route.params.index`

But this is just how you pass the index to the `profile.vue` page, eventually you need to have access to the `users` array which you have in the `hom.vue` page, which means that you are sharing data between components (or pages). I strongly suggest you to use Vuex, the Vue state management, a centralized store for your app. You can check out their documentation here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern